# Generate an array by comparing two arrays and add a key dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

My app receives data from API and saves it in `$scope.newz`.

`bookmarkData` is loaded from LocalStorage.

I am comparing the values of contentId of both the arrays, **$scope.newz** and **$scope.bookmarkData**.

I cannot figure how to save `bookmarkstate : true` **only for matched array items**.

Finally the matched records are to be addedto `$scope.AllnewsList`.

Here is my code

```
if(data.Status.ResponseCode == 200)
  { 
    $("#fetchnews").hide();

    // $("#nodata").show();

    $("#sError").hide();

    //$scope.AllnewsList =  data.contents;

    $scope.newz = data.contents; 
    $scope.bookmarkData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('bookmark'));

    for (var i=0; i < $scope.newz.length; i++)
    {
      for (var j=0; j < $scope.bookmarkData.data.length; j++) 
      {
        if ($scope.newz[i].ContentId == $scope.bookmarkData.data[j].ContentId)
          {
            // console.log($scope.newz[i].ContentId);
            $scope.bookmarkstate == true; 
          }
          else
          {
            $scope.bookmarkstate == false;
          }
      }
    }
    $scope.AllnewsList = $scope.newz;
  }
```

Comment: shahrukh, could you please define your arrays for us to get an idea...?

Comment: @Tirthraj Barot My 2 arrays are 1)$scope.newz (which consist the data from service) and my 2)$scope.bookmarkData(which is saved locally) i want compare there id and when they match i just want to set there state. and the same state should reflect in 3) $scope.AllnewsList to show it in my news.

Comment: is state a property or is it $state?

Comment: $state - this is basically bookmarking the data and even if the service is refreshed the bookmarkstate should stay true for marked data.

Comment: Shahrukh, $state in angularjs is different... check this out.. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Comment: Thats alright.. just give us the keys of all of your arrays..

Comment: @Tirthraj sorry for that state info. it is normal state(true/false). there are many keys like source, title etc and ContentId is one of them and unique for each news.

Comment: alright.. Tell me if the below answer doesn't work...

Comment: The below answer doesn't work.

Comment: Alright.. I shall try it now.

Comment: Check the answer @Sharukh

Comment: and tell me if even this  doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Tirthraj -console.log(newz[i]); till here im able to get the matched data. now the challenge is on assigning this matched data in 3) array as it does not work neither the states change.

Comment: so you need only the matched data in allnewslist array?

Comment: did it solve the problem?

Comment: i checked it is does not work. i have specified the problem below. please check. Thanks lot..

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you're looking **to register for each `newz`** whether or not you have at least one bookmark for.

If that's what you want to do I would recommend setting your `$scope.bookmarkstate` to an array the **same size** as the `newz` array.

That way you can register in each of its cells if the corresponding cell in the `"newz"` array contains a bookmark or not.

```
if(data.Status.ResponseCode == 200)
    { 
       $scope.bookmarkstate = [];
       $("#fetchnews").hide();
       $("#sError").hide();
      $scope.newz = data.contents; 
      $scope.bookmarkData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('bookmark'));
       for (var i=0; i < $scope.newz.length; i++)
        {
          for (var j=0; j < $scope.bookmarkData.data.length; j++) 
          {
              if ($scope.newz[i].ContentId == $scope.bookmarkData.data[j].ContentId)
               {
                 $scope.bookmarkstate[i] == true; 
              }
              else
              {

                 $scope.bookmarkstate[i] == false;
              }
          }
      }
       $scope.AllnewsList = $scope.newz;
   }
```

Let me know how that worked out for you.
Cheers.

Comment: thanks for your response but i comparing the 2 arrays those are $scope.newz and bookmarkData  and im comparing there id(ContentId) if those are matched then the state should be true.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the keys you mentioned in the comment and assuming the dynamic data, I defined your arrays in the following manner..

Kindly correct me if I have misinterpreted your question

```js
var newz = [{contentId : 1, source : 'demoSrc1', title:'title1' },
{contentId : 2, source : 'demoSrc2', title:'title2' },
{contentId : 3, source : 'demoSrc3', title:'title3' },
{contentId : 4, source : 'demoSrc4', title:'title4' },
{contentId : 5, source : 'demoSrc5', title:'title5' },
{contentId : 6, source : 'demoSrc6', title:'title6' },
{contentId : 7, source : 'demoSrc7', title:'title7' },
{contentId : 8, source : 'demoSrc8', title:'title8' }];
//I defined your newz statically for simplicity.

var bookmarkData = [{contentId : 1, source : 'demoSrc1', title:'title1' },
{contentId : 4, source : 'demoSrc4', title:'title4' },
{contentId : 6, source : 'demoSrc6', title:'title6' },
{contentId : 8, source : 'demoSrc8', title:'title8' }];
//SIMILARLY id defined your bookmarkData statically.


var AllnewsList = [];


    for (var i=0; i <  newz.length; i++)
    {
      for (var j=0; j < bookmarkData.length; j++) 
      {
            if (newz[i].contentId == bookmarkData[j].contentId)
          {

            newz[i].bookmarkstate = true; 
            AllnewsList.push(newz[i]);
//            console.log(newz[i]);
          }
          else
          {
            newz[i].bookmarkstate = false;
          }
  //        console.log(newz[i].contentId);

      }
    }
console.log(AllnewsList);
```

Comment: Thanks alot for ur help buddy. i have figured out another way to get this done. which is better to get the false value from api and later change it in local and then compare.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tip : You are not using assignment operator in your code to store status and i will recommend you to use
underscore for this tasks if you want to minimize lines of code.

If i understand you correctly the bookmarkstate array  will have true value for each news if news ContentId is equal to each bookmarkData ContentId else it will store false for each news.
var bookmarkstate = [];
var newz = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "first",
        ContentId: 3
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        name: "second",
        ContentId: 33
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "third",
        ContentId: 3
    }

];
var bookmarkData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "first",
        ContentId: 3
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        name: "second",
        ContentId: 33
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "third",
        ContentId: 3
    }

];

for (var i = 0; i < newz.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < bookmarkData.length; j++) {
        if (newz[i].ContentId == bookmarkData[j].ContentId) {
            bookmarkstate[i] = true; // you were not using assignment operator
        } else {
            bookmarkstate[i] = false;// ou were not using assignment operator
        }

    }
}
console.log(bookmarkstate);
```

Comment: well ill make it more specific about my app. im developing a news app where each article has(ContentId) i have bookmark button when the button is clicked(color or icon changes) the data is stored in local storage. my problem is when i update my news atricles with new news the bookmark button(color) shows false (as if the data is not bookmarked) so i want to prevent this. and show the news is bookmarked.